# SpringBoot - Derby Runtime Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have this below pom.xml file. I am getting this error message while trying to run my application.
**Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.**

I googled and few resources say that this problem should not come for the in-memory database version like H2, Derby etc. Yet, I am running into this problem.

Tried updating application.properties with

```
#PROFILES
spring.profiles.active=dev
#JPA (JpaBaseConfiguration, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration)
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.database=default
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=false
spring.datasource.generate-unique-name=false
```

and with

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:derby:memory:local;create=true
spring.datasource.username=derbyuser
spring.datasource.password=password
```

but no respite. Please let me know what/where I am missing.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.firehose</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootJPA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.15.2.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem while creating a project locally. Have resolved it using below:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```